# PyCharm 2016 does not recognize graphviz package 2.38.xxx

Tags: python, pycharm, graphviz

I have successfully installed Anaconda 4.1.1 for Python version 2.7 on Windows.

Pycharm does not recognize import graphviz module.

Running pip install graphviz is not an option since access to the internet is blocked from within Firm's network.

I have also tried from within Pycharm to import package
From Project Interpreter, all the standard packages are listed except graphviz. Selecting packages list is empty.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me... http://www.alexandrejoseph.com/blog/2016-02-10-install-pygraphviz-mac-osx.html

I just added the install options, pip install pygraphviz --install-option="--include-path=/usr/local/include/graphviz/" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/local/lib/graphviz"